# Possible unhandled promise rejection in react native firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

Im trying so sav data on firestore through react native but when I press the buttom to save data, I get "Possible unhandled promise rejection (id:1); I dont know what else to do. Thanks. There my code below.

My code in App.js

```
async function submit() {
    await db.collection("cities").add({
      name: "Tokyo",
      country: "Japan",
    });
  }
```

My Firebase code

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  authDomain: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  projectId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getFirestore(app);

export default db;
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a `.catch()` to addDoc()?

Comment: Nope. Can you give me an example please? Im new at this. Thank you

Comment: With the information available is not possible to help you, but you should wrap the await call in a try/catch block so you can log the error that is being thrown by the promise db.collection().add(). ```try {  await db.collection("cities").add({
      name: "Tokyo",
      country: "Japan",
    }); } catch(e) { console.log(e)}```

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try that!

Comment: Sorry, Im getting this error now :  in the console log: "_Firebase.default.collection is not a function"